# Trying to display all posts in my archive page but it is only returning the page content

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, archive, posts

I'm having a problem with displaying all posts in my archive page using the have_posts loop. When I try to return the title and the content, it returns the template page's title and content instead of the posts' content.

What I did to try and fix it is I ran a WP_Query post loop which grabs all the posts of post type = post and it displays the content just fine. The only problem is I want a dynamic archive page so when users select a tag - it will take them to an archive page with all the posts containing that tag. Since I am running a specific WP_Query, all my archive pages display all the posts with the post-type = post.

My guess is that I have to run a simple have_posts loop instead of running WP_Query in order for my archive page to dynamic.

How I set up my archive page: I have a file called archive.php which I gave the template name of Archives and created a page for it on wp-admin and titled it Blog.

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying archive pages
 * Template Name: Archives
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Seventeen
 * @since 1.0
 * @version 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

  <div class="d-flex flex-wrap archive-wrap">

   <div class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main d-flex justify-content-center flex-wrap" role="main">

    <?php // Show the selected frontpage content.
    if ( have_posts() ) :
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <div class="archive-header col-10 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column">
            <?php
                the_title( '<h1 class="archive-title">', '</h1>' );
                the_content( '<h1 class="archive-title">', '</h1>'); 
            ?>

        </div><!-- .page-header -->

    <?php

        get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', 'archive' );

        endwhile;

        the_posts_pagination( array(
            'prev_text' => twentyseventeen_get_svg( array( 'icon' => 'arrow-left' ) ) . '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Previous page', 'twentyseventeen' ) . '</span>',
            'next_text' => '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Next page', 'twentyseventeen' ) . '</span>' . twentyseventeen_get_svg( array( 'icon' => 'arrow-right' ) ),
            'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Page', 'twentyseventeen' ) . ' </span>',
        ) );

    endif; ?>

    <div class="col-10 col-md-3 offset-lg-1 sidebar-4-container">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-4' ); ?>
    </div>


    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

</div><!-- .wrap -->

<?php get_footer();
```

Inside my template content archive file I have the following:

```
<?php 
 // the query
 $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', 
 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>-1)); ?>

<?php if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : ?>


    <!-- the loop -->
    <?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>
    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="col-12 article-container">
        <div class="article-image-div" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post_id, 'large' );  ?> ');"></div>
        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>      
        <h5>by <?php echo get_the_author(); ?></h5>
        <?php echo apply_filters( 'the_content', wp_trim_words( strip_tags( $post->post_content ), 55 ) ); ?>

        <hr align="left">   
    </div>


    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- end of the loop -->


    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Query_posts or get_posts instead of 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/